# Convert ((50^A)*((((50^B)(((50^C)+1)/(4)))+1)/(4)))/(4) to MathJax?

Tags: mathematical-programming

I need help coverting  these two question to Math Jax
((50^A)*((((50^B)(((50^C)+1)/(4)))+1)/(4)))/(4)
and 
(((50^A)(50^B)(50^C))/(4^2)) + (((50^A)(50^B))/(4^2))+((50^A)/(4))+(1/4)
I don't know how to do it, for a mathstack exchange question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should ask questions about how to ask on MathStack on their meta site! Each site on Stack Exchange has a Meta site to ask questions about asking questions! They even have a tutorial there: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

However, learning how to typeset mathematics is something Computer Science students and researchers have to learn how to do, so perhaps it could be considered just about on-topic!

[MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) is based on [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) which is a page description language used for writing documents which happens to be quite good at writing maths. LaTeX (created  by [Leslie Lamport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_Lamport)) was built upon [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) which was created by [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth). Both Computer Scientists.

The simplest way of using MathJax is to just use the dollar symbol `$` to quote or surround your formula. If we take your first formula:

```
((50^A)*((((50^B)(((50^C)+1)/(4)))+1)/(4)))/(4)
```

Put it with the dollars, we get:

```
$((50^A)*((((50^B)(((50^C)+1)/(4)))+1)/(4)))/(4)$
```

which displays this:

$((50^A)*((((50^B)(((50^C)+1)/(4)))+1)/(4)))/(4)$

Now perhaps you want that to be a bit neater. They you can replace the slashes by some better arrangement and make them fractions. In MathJax w can invoke layout function by using the backslash `\` to indicate a layout function name and give its arguments within curly braces `{}`. We want the `\frac` function like this:

```
$\frac{((50^A)*((((50^B)(((50^C)+1)/(4)))+1)/(4)))}{(4)}$
```

$\frac{((50^A)*((((50^B)(((50^C)+1)/(4)))+1)/(4)))}{(4)}$

We can do that again for each fraction:

```
$\frac{((50^A)*(((\frac{(50^B)((\frac{(50^C)+1)}{(4)}))+1)}{(4)}))}{(4)}$
```

$\frac{((50^A)*(((\frac{(50^B)((\frac{(50^C)+1)}{(4)}))+1)}{(4)}))}{(4)}$

Which can be tidied up further, but that gives you the basics!

Comment: Someone who is better at MathJax might want to fix my basic hashup here!